# Tornado : [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, tornado

I'm trying to run this program so that I can understand asynchronous programming using tornado.

```py
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

def handle_response(response):
      url = response.request.url
      data = response.body
      print('{}: {} bytes: {}'.format(url, len(data), data))

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()

http_client.fetch(url, handle_response)
 
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

However, I am getting this error when I am trying to run it

`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSL error was because Python 3.7 does not rely on MacOS' openSSL anymore. It comes with its own openSSL bundled and doesn't have access on MacOS' root certificates.
So all I needed to do was run the following command-

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code using python3 and it operated as expected. You may want to troubleshoot connecting to that website from your computer either via a browser or by using curl.

This indicates that for some reason the http client is not able to validate the SSL cert for the website. If you cannot access the page in your browser then you need to determine why that it, it could be due to a DNS based ad/content blocker or other (unknown) things.

EDIT: it could also be due to the time one your computer drifting too far from the actual time.

Comment: I am able to access the webpage via browser as well as by using curl. I am using VSCode IDE on mac and my python interpreter version is 3.7.